# Does a model's save() method get called when using loaddata for fixtures?

Tags: django, django-models, fixtures

I'm trying to generate an automatic slug for a model whenever it is empty, from another field. This is the code:

```
class Position(RichText):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)

    def position_description(self):
        return self.content

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)

        super(Position, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I load initial fixtures with loaddata, it seems the `save()` method is never triggered. Is this normal behavior? How can I catch fixtures too?

Comment: but the objects weren't saved (using `save()`) before they were dumped?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior, from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture):

> When fixture files are processed, the data is saved to the database as
>   is. Model defined save methods and pre_save signals are not called

.

Comment: it would seem that post_save() is, though I don't know why they would leave that on... But I have UserProfile being created with a post_save signal and using loaddata later on causes some mismatches between user.id's and userprofile.userid's...

Comment: and to answer myself... checking for _raw_ seems to do the trick  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499791/how-do-i-prevent-fixtures-from-conflicting-with-django-post-save-signal-code