# How to disable/disconnect m2m_changed signal during testing?

Tags: django, signals

I am trying to load a fixture during a django test case, but `m2m_changed` signal kicks in and it gives an error (the signal checks that a foreignkey is in a related state).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11409794/618018) suggests using the `disable_for_loaddata` decorator, but `m2m_changed` doesn't have a `raw` [field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#m2m-changed).

I have tried:

```
class DaysTests(APITestCase):
    fixtures = ['initial_data.json'] # fixture is loaded before disabling m2m_changed
    def setUp(self):
        m2m_changed.disconnect(days_handler, sender=Foo.days.through)

    def test_api(self):
        # test logic.
```

Initial data is loaded before disabling the `m2m_changed` signal.

What is the right way to disconnect/disable a `m2m_changed` signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to try to disable this signal not in setUp method but in setUpClass because it's executed before loading fixtures. This is a possible way to use it:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    super(DaysTests, cls).setUpClass()
    m2m_changed.disconnect(...)
```