# IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture

Tags: python, django

I upload my first Django-project into DigitalOcean. After command `python manage.py loaddata initial_data.json`, I have received this message:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture
>   '/webapps/django_shop/shop/initial_data.json': Could not load
>   contenttypes.ContentType(pk=3): duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "django_content_type_app_label_76bd3d3b_uniq" DETAIL:  Key
>   (app_label, model)=(auth, permission) already exists.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've generated fixtures that include Django's default data set, i.e. the built-in entries that are inserted normally as part of the first `migrate` run for some of Django's plumbing data types.

You should review your fixture process, because content type entries will be created automatically when your (and Django's) apps' migrations are run, so they should not be present in fixtures. It's possible there are other tables that will have this same problem, so now would be a good time to make sure you're not including any other data that would result in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I solved this way

##### DB with data to export from

```
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db.json
```

##### New DB to import to

```
python manage.py flush
```

// Important! Disable all signals on models pre_save and post_save

```
python manage.py loaddata db.json
```

// Do not forget to enable all signals that you disabled

Comment: Commenting out "pre_save" and "post_save" solved my issue.

Comment: Is there a way to silence specific signals and/or add it as parameter to the `loaddata` command? I'd like to automate the process without changing the models.
update: seems like its possible using the passed "raw" arg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499791/how-do-i-prevent-fixtures-from-conflicting-with-django-post-save-signal-code

Comment: @Lukr if you want to run the loaddata command programmatically, you can disconnect the signals you that want to disable with Signal.disconnect() command, run the loaddata command then reconnect the signals Signal.connect(), just an alternative to using raw. This will give you a full control of the process